# How to implement react js bulid in Laravel 10 for production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, build

I have React JS build in react.zip file.

File stature is like this:

```
react
|    asset-manifest.json
|___ assets
|    |    css
|    |    fonts
|    |    javascript
|    |    media
|    |    sass
|    favicon.ico
|    index.html
|    logo192.png
|    manifest.json
|    robots.txt
|___ static
|    |___ css
|    |    |    main.f3bcd66c.css
|    |    |    main.f3bcd66c.css.map
|    |___ js
|    |    |    787.f4bb98cd.chunk.js
|    |    |    787.f4bb98cd.chunk.map
|    |    |    main.af7c97e4.js
|    |    |    main.af7c97e4.js.LICENSE.txt
|    |    |    main.af7c97e4.js.map
```

How to implement this build in Laravel project for view on production server.

I have tried this to build unzip in side public folder.

1. Route defined :

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('frontend.index');
    });
```

2. root/resource/view/frontend/index.blade.php code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <title>Your Application Name</title>

            <script src="{{ asset('react/static/js/main.af7c97e4.js') }}" defer></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Some react build files data looks like this :
a) asset-manifest.json code :

```
    {
      "files": {
        "main.css": "/static/css/main.f3bcd66c.css",
        "main.js": "/static/js/main.af7c97e4.js",
        "static/js/787.f4bb98cd.chunk.js": "/static/js/787.f4bb98cd.chunk.js",
        "index.html": "/index.html",
        "main.f3bcd66c.css.map": "/static/css/main.f3bcd66c.css.map",
        "main.af7c97e4.js.map": "/static/js/main.af7c97e4.js.map",
        "787.f4bb98cd.chunk.js.map": "/static/js/787.f4bb98cd.chunk.js.map"
      },
      "entrypoints": [
        "static/css/main.f3bcd66c.css",
        "static/js/main.af7c97e4.js"
      ]
    }
```

b) index.html code :

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <title>React App</title>
        <base href="/./" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
        <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.af7c97e4.js"></script>
        <link href="/static/css/main.f3bcd66c.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="./assets/javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/javascript/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/javascript/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/javascript/gsap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/javascript/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/javascript/gsap/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/javascript/serviceSec.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Now when I hit url '/' showing error in console :

> Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined in OwlCarousel.js file.

Where is issue to implement this react js build?